# Migrating Bot Framework to Azure Bot Service: Subscription not in list

Tags: azure, migration, botframework

When trying to migrate my bot on https://dev.botframework.com/bots to Azure Bot Service the selection list of the target subscription only includes one of my several Azure subscriptions for this user. The subscription shown is the wrong one - and all others - including the correct one - are missing.

What I've tried

- The user (bot/settings) is correct and matching the subscription Admin user
- Set the desired subscription to "IsDefault" using PowerShell (Select-AzureSubscription)

The general functionality seems to work, when selecting the displayed subscription, the migration is correctly done (what of course doesn't help because it's not the desired one).

Comment: If you haven't contacted Azure support yet, I suggest doing so.